# How assign numbers range into a simple bash variable

Tags: bash, variable, numeric-data

How assign numbers sequence into bash variable as this fail:

```
$ n={0..9}; echo $n
{0..9}
$ n=\"{0..9}\"; echo $n
"{0..9}"

$ eval n={0..9}; echo $n
$ eval n=\"{0..9}\"; echo $n
9

$ n=`eval {0..9}`; echo $n
bash: 0: command not found
```

Please guide to the correct one

Comment: What do you want `n` to contain? Perhaps `n = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`, i.e. a string of numbers? Or an array of numbers? What do you want to do with this `n`?

Answer (score 6):

Assign with:

```
$ n=({0..9})
```

Using `n=(x)` means `n` is an array with `x` as its contents.

Then output a full array with:

```
$ echo "${n[@]}"
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

or output one element at a time with

```
$ for i in "${n[@]}"; do
>   printf "%s " "$i"
> done
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

or access a specific element with:

```
$ echo "${n[0]}"
0
```

There is lots of info already available if you search for "[bash array](https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-arrays/)"

Answer (score 3):

Here's two methods:

1. use an array

   ```
   $ n=( {0..9} )
   $ declare -p n
   declare -a n=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [6]="6" [7]="7" [8]="8" [9]="9")
   ```
2. expand the range into a single string

   ```
   $ n=$(printf "%s" {0..9})
   $ declare -p n
   declare -- n="0123456789"
   ```